# I'm looking for ways to convert Bezier curves into .svg images

Tags: p-lang, potrace

I'm trying to use potrace in python to convert a directory of .pngs into .svgs. The .pngs in question are traced in black and white. The code I'm currently using traces just fine, but it outputs data as a bunch of coordinates of how steep the curve is, when to start the curve, and when to stop it. From what I've seen, I think that these are Bezier curves. I'm looking for a way to convert that data into a .svg in an automated fashion.

Example output:
Start (122.938294)
P1 (67.452531
P2 (82.381935)
End (93.747321)
Wiki page about Bezier curves: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve

I've looked at a bunch of information online and it seems like there aren't a lot of people with this problem. Any help would be appreciated.
The code I'm using is literally copy-pasted from the pypi potrace article here: https://pypi.org/project/pypotrace/

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.